# How to Convert XML Webservice response data in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I am getting data from xml webservice. The data is coming in:

`<![CDATA]>` like `<![CDATA[Semi-Detached, Didcot]]>`.

I have used HtmlEncode to convert or get data from above tag but unable to get data. I wanna get data from `<![CDATA]>` tag and display in a grid.

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Hi Deepak - please take some time to accept the best answers to your previous questions.  You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Deepak, we're going to need a larger snippet of the XML - one with enough tags that we can give a sensible answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using linq to xml, something along the lines of

```
var xml = XDocuemnt.Parse(responseString);

var result from x in xml.Descendants("nodeName").
           where x.Attribute("ID") == 1
           select x.something;
```

There are loads of methods for this.

Comment: My data is coming in dataset and I am not using Linq. My application is in VS 2005.